# c++ winsock code does not work in its original solution/project in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, class, winsock

I am not 100% sure if I shall become insane...

As mentioned in many many other posts, I am writing this Connection class which stats up winsock, creates some sockets, binds them and let´s you send and receive some data...

I made this within my Server-project...
But , everytime i wanted to test the connection part of the server (most of the other parts are already working fine) it always goes on strike O_o... ALWAYS!!!...

What I tried to fix it:
1. rewrite the send & recv parts
2. rewrite the whole class multiple times without copying anything from the existing stuff before...
3. Write a special test client...
4. Write a whole new simple send/recv-udp-server programm to test, wether it may be based on some ports, that are blocked or something like that...

Still does not work...

Well... so a few minutes i came up with the idea, that I could try to copy the code into a new project and try it then (I don´t know what made try this - the frustration?.

But wooaaaaaah... IT WORKS:...

Now my Question to anyone familiar with Visual Studio...:

Why the HELL doesn´t it work in the original soultion/project, but In a totally new solution/project...???????

This drives me crazy, because I have to copy/rewrite everything into a new solution and reorganize this shit-.-....

Comment: What exactly does not work? Any error messages?

Comment: As mentioned above, it does not have to do with code... 

When I copy the class (header & code file) into a new solution/project... it works... 

The problem is, that I want it to work in the old project/solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... I am not sure, why this problem appeared...

But the solution was to create a new solution and insert the "old" files...

finally it works :)...

I hope it wasn´t the windows firewall, but I did check this...

Answer (score 1):

All that I can say is to check all properties of old project which does not work against new project working...

It should be something different since you said that you did not modify the source code.

Comment: With the informations you gave us. I have no clue.

The only thing which is certain, there is something wrong with the project settings or with the Visual Studio 2010 settings.

First thing I would do is to compare (using a compare tool) the project files.

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally the IDE will get confused and fail to correctly determine what needs to be recompiled. When strange stuff happens try "Rebuild Solution", or better yet, exit from the IDE and then rebuild.

Comment: already done that multiple times... never helps... same while deleting info files and that stuff...

I wrote a sample server into the main(), which does not work, too...

So I think it just blocks my winsock^^...

Guess I´ll have to create a new solution and import everything...